# Predefine the factors in table function in R

Tags: r, refactoring, predefined-variables

I would like to predefine the levels of the table function to make the results comparable among distinct datasets. Let's say that I would like to compare obj1 and obj2:

```
obj1 <-c(1,1,1,2,3)

obj2 <- c(1,1,1,2,2)
```

If I use table function on them the results have different factors:

```
> table(obj1)
obj1
1 2 3
3 1 1
> table(obj2)
obj2
1 2
3 2
```

I tried to predefine the levels without success:

```
table(obj2, deparse.level = 3)
```

> Error in vapply(l[fixup], function(x) switch(deparse.level + 1, "",
>   if (is.symbol(x)) as.character(x) else "",  :
>         values must be length 1,
>        but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 0

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now,  you just have numbers. If you make the obj's factors,  you can declare the factor levels.

```
obj1 <- factor(c(1,1,1,2,3), levels=1:3)
obj2 <- factor(c(1,1,1,2,2), levels=1:3)
table(obj1)
obj1
1 2 3 
3 1 1 
table(obj2)
obj2
1 2 3 
3 2 0
```